# Add values to a dataframe against some particular ID in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID  Name  City
1   Ali   swl
2   Sana  lhr
3   Ahad  khi
4   ABC   fsd
```

And a list of values like (1,2,1):

```
val nums: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 1)
```

I want to add these values against `ID == 3`. So that DataFrame looks like:

```
ID  Name  City  newCol  newCol2  newCol3
1   Ali   swl    null     null    null
2   Sana  lhr    null     null    null
3   Ahad  khi     1        2        1
4   ABC   fsd    null     null    null
```

I wonder if it is possible? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you can convert it to `DataFrame` with single array column and then "decompose" the array column into columns as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit}
import spark.implicits._

val numsDf =
  Seq(nums)
    .toDF("nums")
    .select(nums.indices.map(i => col("nums")(i).alias(s"newCol$i")): _*)
```

After that you can use outer join for joining `data` to `numsDf` with `ID == 3` condition as follows:

```
val resultDf = data.join(numsDf, data.col("ID") === lit(3), "outer")
```

`resultDf.show()` will print:

```
+---+----+----+-------+-------+-------+
| ID|Name|City|newCol0|newCol1|newCol2|
+---+----+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1| Ali| swl|   null|   null|   null|
|  2|Sana| lhr|   null|   null|   null|
|  3|Ahad| khi|      1|      2|      3|
|  4| ABC| fsd|   null|   null|   null|
+---+----+----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Make sure you have added `spark.sql.crossJoin.crossJoin.enabled = true` option to the spark session:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  ...
  .config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", value = true)
  .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: It throws error on ```.select```. ```Can't resolve overloaded method 'select'```. Why this is causing an issue ?

Comment: Could you provide your code? Because I checked my own code and it works well

Comment: Isn't it because of spark version?

Comment: You can share it via [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/). Also I used `2.4.4` version of Spark with Scala `2.11.12`

Comment: I am using Spark 2.4.4 with Scala 2.11.12

Comment: Make sure you have the following imports: `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit}` and `import spark.implicits._`

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: I've added the above imports but now it is throwing another exception.

Comment: ```Detected implicit cartesian product for FULL OUTER join between logical plans.```

Comment: Add `config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", value = true)` to your spark session

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem. Thank you so much. Your effort is really appreciable.

Comment: And now if I have another list of values agains ```ID===4```?

Comment: Then you can change the condition, e.g. `anotherData.col("ID") === lit(4)`

Comment: But it will add 3 more columns as well.

Comment: It will add as much columns as how much data in your list

Comment: Can't I add new values in ```resultDf```?

Comment: I mean I don't need new columns but I want to alter ```resultDf```.

Comment: You can filter out columns by using `select` operator

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Its possible.

Use `when` for populating matched values & `otherwise` for not matched values.

I have used zipWithIndex for making column names unique.

Please check below code.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> val df = Seq((1,"Ali","swl"),(2,"Sana","lhr"),(3,"Ahad","khi"),(4,"ABC","fsd")).toDF("id","name","city") // Creating DataFrame with given sample data.
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val nums = List(1,2,1) // List values.
nums: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 1)

scala> val filterData = List(3,4)

scala> spark.time{ nums.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(df)((df,c) => df.withColumn(s"newCol${c._2}",when($"id".isin(filterData:_*),c._1).otherwise(null))).show(false) } // Used zipWithIndex to make column names unique.
+---+----+----+-------+-------+-------+
|id |name|city|newCol0|newCol1|newCol2|
+---+----+----+-------+-------+-------+
|1  |Ali |swl |null   |null   |null   |
|2  |Sana|lhr |null   |null   |null   |
|3  |Ahad|khi |1      |2      |1      |
|4  |ABC |fsd |1      |2      |1      |
+---+----+----+-------+-------+-------+

Time taken: 43 ms

scala>
```

Comment: Throw an error on ```when```. ```Can't resolve symbol when```. What is the issue?

Comment: are you checking in scala shell ? or using any idea ?

Comment: I'm using intellij idea IDE.

Comment: have you imported functions ?  if not try  - import org.apache.spark.sql.function._

Comment: Ok, Please accept answer or upvote if it helps to solve problem.

Comment: Okay after this if I again want to add values against ID=4?

Comment: Updated Answer based on your input, Please check & let me know if not working..

Comment: I've checked this. But maybe I have different list of values agains ID=4.